# Can ITextSharp perform all of these functions?

Tags: .net, pdf, pdf-generation, itext

I am evaluating ITextSharp and here is a list of things that I need to achieve using only ITextSharp Library:

1. Open/Edit PDF document of any version (e.g. 1.4,1.5,1.6,1.7)
2. Manipulate PDF Forms and get Field positions of each of the fields present in a PDF form.
3. Draw fields/text on any custom location in the PDF document.
4. Merge multiple PDF documents.
5. Add watermarks.
6. Handle different page sizes of the PDF document.
7. Handle page angles
8. Add margins to a page and redraw a page
9. Layer support

I know that some of these are very basic and ITextSharp can do them but have included them in this list just for the sake of completion.

So my question is

Can I do all of the above with ITextSharp library?

Thanks,
M

Comment: While @Bruno tried to answer your requirements, in my opinion your requirements are too vague. E.g. what do you mean by "Layer support"? Do you mean features like adding content to a specific layer and changing default visibilities of given layers? Or do you mean high level features like moving all content of a single layer on a page into the background, or onto a second page, with a single method call?

Comment: @mkl maybe we shouldn't assume that Bhatti knows what he's asking. He has probably been given a task and instead of doing some research, he thought: let's throw the requirements given by my customer on StackOverflow and see if some idiot is willing to do the thinking in my place.

Comment: @Bruno :evilbruno: ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. *Open/Edit PDF document of any version (e.g. 1.4,1.5,1.6,1.7):* `PdfReader` can open files of all those versions. `PdfCopy`, `PdfSmartCopy` and `PdfStamper` can be used to manipulate those documents (assemble, stamp,...).
2. *Manipulate PDF Forms and get Field positions of each of the fields present in a PDF form.* Yes.

   - [How to fill out a pdf file programmatically?](http://developers.itextpdf.com/question/how-fill-out-pdf-file-programmatically-acroform-technology)
   - [How to flatten a XFA PDF Form using iTextSharp?](http://developers.itextpdf.com/question/how-flatten-xfa-pdf-form-using-itextsharp)
   - [How to find the absolute position and dimension of a field?](http://developers.itextpdf.com/question/how-find-absolute-position-and-dimension-field)
   - [How to move an AcroForm field?](http://developers.itextpdf.com/question/how-move-acroform-field)
   - [How to change the text color of an AcroForm field?](http://developers.itextpdf.com/question/how-change-text-color-acroform-field)
3. *Draw fields/text on any custom location in the PDF document.* If you have the page number and the coordinates, you can add fields.

   - [How can I add a new AcroForm field to a PDF?](http://developers.itextpdf.com/question/how-can-i-add-new-acroform-field-pdf)
4. *Merge multiple PDF documents.* That's what `PdfCopy` and `PdfSmartCopy` are about.

   - [How to merge documents correctly?](http://developers.itextpdf.com/question/how-merge-documents-correctly)
   - [How to merge forms from different files into one PDF?](http://developers.itextpdf.com/question/how-merge-forms-different-files-one-pdf)
   - [Why does the function to concatenate / merge PDFs cause issues in some cases?](http://developers.itextpdf.com/question/why-does-function-concatenate-merge-pdfs-cause-issues-some-cases)
5. *Add watermarks.* That's what `PdfStamper` is about.

   - [How to watermark PDFs using text or images?](http://developers.itextpdf.com/question/how-watermark-pdfs-using-text-or-images)
   - [How to add an image watermark to a PDF file?](http://developers.itextpdf.com/question/how-add-image-watermark-pdf-file)
   - [How to add a watermark to a page with an opaque image?](http://developers.itextpdf.com/question/how-add-watermark-page-opaque-image)
6. *Handle different page sizes of the PDF document.* Of course!

   - [How to set the page size to Envelope size with Landscape orientation?](http://developers.itextpdf.com/question/how-set-page-size-envelope-size-landscape-orientation)
   - [How to create a document with unequal page sizes?](http://developers.itextpdf.com/question/how-create-document-unequal-page-sizes)
   - [How to define the page size based on the content?](http://developers.itextpdf.com/question/how-define-page-size-based-content)
   - [How to match the size of graphics with the size of a page?](http://developers.itextpdf.com/question/how-match-size-graphics-size-page)
7. *Handle page angles.* ISO-32000-1 allows page angles that are a multiple of 90, so does iText.

   - [How do I rotate a PDF page to an arbitrary angle?](http://developers.itextpdf.com/question/how-do-i-rotate-pdf-page-arbitrary-angle)
   - [How to rotate a page 90 degrees?](http://developers.itextpdf.com/question/how-rotate-page-90-degrees)
8. *Add margins to a page and redraw a page.* Change page size to add margins: yes. Redraw page: what do you mean? Reflow usually isn't possible in general. Are you talking about Tagged PDF? iText has a `PdfImportedPage` class that can be used to reuse pages.

   - [How to extend the page size of a PDF to add a watermark?](http://developers.itextpdf.com/question/how-extend-page-size-pdf-add-watermark)
   - [How to reuse a page from one PDF document into another PDF document?](http://developers.itextpdf.com/question/how-reuse-page-one-pdf-document-another-pdf-document)
9. *Layer support.* Define "layer". If you refer to OCG, then yes, iText supports it. If you refer to something else, please explain.

   - [How to change the order of Optional Content Groups?](http://developers.itextpdf.com/question/how-change-order-optional-content-groups)
   - [How to set the OCG state of an existing PDF?](http://developers.itextpdf.com/question/how-set-ocg-state-existing-pdf)

   Note that it's also possible that you want to superimpose content as explained in [How to superimpose pages from existing documents into another document?](http://developers.itextpdf.com/question/how-superimpose-pages-existing-documents-another-document)

Basically, my answer is: you should read [the official documentation](http://developers.itextpdf.com/) before asking a question like this on StackOverflow.

Comment: thanks a lot Bruno. I just wanted reassurance from someone to make sure that I am not digging a new hole for myself